foundry slate data driven html widget?
I am trying to use a if statement to control the background color of my button.
my code look like this but is not working. also can you do a else/if statement in html to add 2 more colors.
thanks
     <div class="cards">
  {{#each f_WB.Outgoing_AC_ID}}
      <div class="cards">
      <div class="gld-ListTable-itemButtons">
       <a class="pt-button pt-icon-airplane
            {{#if (eq (AC_status @index): 'Green')}}
        green
        {{/if}}
        " 
        selection="{{this}}" >
        ***{{lookup  f_WB.Outgoing_AC_ID @index}}*** &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{lookup f_WB.dept_planned @index}}
        <br>
         {{lookup  f_WB.event_out @index}} &nbsp;
       </a>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>

result should look like this but green if true.
enter image description here
I have tried all different syntax and class changes i could think of,
